# Check the CPU name in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, comparison, cpu

I'm trying to know if the processor name is equal or similar to a specific string value, but I don't find a good solution. Here is my code

```
$nameCPU = WMIC CPU Get Name
Write-host $nameCPU[2]   # The server has two different CPUs

$CheckName = $nameCPU[2] -eq "Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5118 CPU @ 2.30GHz"

Write-Host $CheckName
```

The output is something like this :

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5118 CPU @ 2.30GHz
False
```

`$CheckName` is always False

Someone can help me ? Thanks

Comment: Give this a try `(Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor).Name -eq 'Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5118 CPU @ 2.30GHz'`

Comment: I have this result :
 (Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor).Name -eq 'Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5118 CPU @ 2.30GHz'
Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5118 CPU @ 2.30GHz
Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5118 CPU @ 2.30GHz

Comment: Change `-eq` to `-in` if you have more than one processor, that would return `$true`

Comment: `$CheckName`  is always False because there are spaces after "2.30GHz" in your wmic response

Comment: i guess -Match will work

Comment: For the spaces after 2.30GHz, it is correct. They are two more spaces.
Unfortunately -Match does not work in my case, neither -in

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Win32_Processor` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor) to get your CPU Name, the cmdlet you should use to query this class is [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.2).

Normally you would use `-eq` to compare 2 scalar values however if your server may have more than 1 CPU then the safest way to check it would be by using [`-in` or `-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators). Worth noting that both operators look for **exact values** in an array. Wildcards or regex don't work for them.

```
$cpuInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor
$cpuInfo.Name -contains "Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5118 CPU @ 2.30GHz" # should be True
```

Comment: Yes !!
 I have a True result ! Perfect 
Thanks a lot